# How to run a JS application on desktop and call C code?

Tags: javascript, webgl, desktop-application

I have an web app (WebGL/HTML5/JS) that is very computationally demanding. I want to turn this into a desktop app. I have heard of app.js, http://appjs.com but the problem here will be WebGL ?

The reason I want to turn it into a desktop app is because I want to call unix system commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Electron](https://electronjs.org/) would probably be a better choice since it is still actively maintained and AppJS is not. Electron is Chromium based so it supports WebGL. [Here is an example](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/webgl) of using WebGL with Electron.

[NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) is a similar project. There are some [technical reasons](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/development/atom-shell-vs-node-webkit.md) that you might want to prefer Electron over NW.js.

Both give you access to [Node](http://nodejs.org/), so you should be able to call system commands using the [child process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).